# Firebase authentication error code 5

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to login to firebase using google login. The google login is successful. After this I invoke authWithOAuthToken and I am getting below error.

> Due to another authentication attempt, this authentication attempt was aborted before it could complete. Error Code = -5

**Few other questions:**

- Do we need to call authWithOAuthToken at all (after google login)? I noticed I could add data to firebase database even without call.
- If above is not required, how can I get uid (which is firebase user id same across providers). At present we can get this from AuthData.

**Code Snippet Below**.

```
baseFirebaseRef.authWithOAuthToken("google", oAuthTokenStr, new Firebase.AuthResultHandler() {
  // @Override
  public void onAuthenticated(AuthData authData) {
  // the Google user is now authenticated with your Firebase app
        Log.d(currentScreenName, "------On Firebase Authentication. Success");
   }

  // @Override
  public void onAuthenticationError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
       // there was an error
        Log.e(currentScreenName, "------Error On Firebase Authentication......." + firebaseError.getDetails() +
             "Error Message = "+ firebaseError.getMessage() + " Error Code = "+ firebaseError.getCode()) ;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I called unauth() and then called authWithOAuthToken().